# SolrCloud: workaround for classic pagination with "start,rows" parameters

Tags: performance, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have SolrCloud with 3 shards.

**My purpose**: select and process all products from category.

**Current implementation**: Portion selection in cycle.

- 1st iteration: q=cat:1&start=0&rows=100
- 2nd iteration: q=cat:1&start=100&rows=100
- 3th: q=cat:1&start=200&rows=100

...

But growing "start", performance is down. Explanation here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch

> Makes it more inefficient to use a high "start" parameter. For
>   example, if you request start=500000&rows=25 on an index with 500,000+
>   docs per shard, this will currently result in 500,000 records getting
>   sent over the network from the shard to the coordinating Solr
>   instance. If you had a single-shard index, in contrast, only 25
>   records would ever get sent over the network. (Granted, setting start
>   this high is not something many people need to do.)

What ideas how I can walk around all records in category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another way to do more effective pagination in Solr - [Cursors](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results) - which uses the current place in the sort instead. This is particularly useful for deep pagination.

See the section about [Cursors at the Pagination of Results](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results) wiki page. This should speed up delivery as the Server should be able to do a sort of its local documents, decide where it is in that sequence and return 25 documents after that document.

UPDATE: Also useful link [coming-soon-to-solr-efficient-cursor-based-iteration-of-large-result-sets](http://searchhub.org/2013/12/12/coming-soon-to-solr-efficient-cursor-based-iteration-of-large-result-sets/)

Comment: +1 this appears to be a better approach that what I've described - I suggest taking some of the info from the underlying link and reproducing here (1) passing the cursorMark parameter and showing the nextCursorMark field in the results & (2) sort must include the unique key of the index.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is "no" - it's a limitation of how Solr does sharding. Instead, can you amass a list of document unique keys outside of Solr - presumably from a backing database - and then retrieve from the index using sets of those keys instead?

e.g. `ID:(1 OR 2 OR 3 OR ...very long list...)`

Or, if the unique keys are numeric you could use a moving range instead:

`ID:[1 TO 1000]` then `ID:[1001 TO 2000]` and so forth.

In both options above you'd also restrict by category as well. They both should avoid the slow down associated with windowing however.